# How to provide SERVICE_NAME in the connection options in mysql npm?

Tags: mysql, node.js, jdbc, tcp, node-mysql

I have a JDBC connection string something like this

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1711))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1712)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))
```

I have created the connection as

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "hostname",
    port: "1711",
    user: "user", 
    password: "password"
});
```

How do I also provide SERVICE_NAME (like the jdbc string) to the connection options?
I am getting the following error without it:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED <some_ip>:1711
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1028:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1051:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
    --------------------
```

EDIT:
Changing the port to 1712 gives me a different error after taking a lot of time.

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (..\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:113:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (..\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:186:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

EDIT: Sorry. I didn't see the database was oracle and started trying mysql directly.

Comment: I don't think create connection of mysql module accepts port value as parameter, can you check without it https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction

Comment: according to [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#connection-options) it accepts port value as parameter. Removing the port parameter (which defaults port to 3306) gives me the same above error.

Comment: have you checked that your mysql server is running on `1711` port?

Comment: @abdulbarik provided the edit to the post.

Comment: simple question have you test your mysql server running on port whatever your are trying to give by console instead of code base?

Comment: What has an Oracle database JDBC connection string to do with a MySQL connection on node.js? MySQL != Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your mysql server is running on port `1711` not default port.
And if you are getting `Connection lost` error mean there are something wrong on your network try to reconnect your server after sometime.

```
var conn;

function handleDisconnect() {
  conn = mysql.createConnection(//your config); 


  conn.connect(function(err) {              
    if(err) {                                    
      console.log('error when connecting to database:', err);
      setTimeout(handleDisconnectConnection, 5000); 
    }                                     
  });                                    

  connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('db error', err);
    if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { 
      handleDisconnectConnection();                        
    } else {                                      
      throw err;                                  
    }
  });
}

handleDisconnectConnection();
```

Hope that will work for you